# Firebase limit on the number of observers/listeners

Tags: ios, firebase

In Firebase, we can add an observer in iOS using something like `observeEventType:withBlock:`. Is there a limit on the number of observers that can be attached from one client ?

Comment: No there is not, there is a limit on clients, but not listeners within an individual client.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There is no limit on the number of listeners that may be attached from one client. Also note that listeners are generally inexpensive, so it is recommended that you use them as most convenient in your application.

Comment: Hi Rob... just stumbled upon this answer. Just to be clear... I have an iOS app where I would like to have every item in the feed listen for changes. So that could potentially be hundreds of listeners for each person using the app. Does that sound reasonable? Will it impact the billing plan I'm on?

Comment: Sounds reasonable. No impact on billing; billing is tied to concurrent connections, and all listeners are pipelined over one connection per client.

Comment: So under the hood, are listeners implemented via push or polling? When  you say, inexpensive, are you referring to cloud processing, phone cpu, network traffic or all of the above?

Comment: Listeners are registered with the server, and maintained in the client (i.e. if you are disconnected from the server and need to reconnect, the client knows where to re-listen). Attaching a new listener uses the same existing connection as all other listeners and writes, so all that is involved is a small amount of network traffic to register the listener, and updates are then pushed by the server as data changes (as opposed to having a client that expensively polled the server for changes across each listener).

Comment: Is this the same as a snapshot listener?  Because here (https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/best-practices) it says : Keep the number of snapshot listeners per client under 100.

Comment: @Anthony In concept, these are the same things. However, this answer (above) is for the Firebase Realtime Database, and the document that you are linking to is for Cloud Firestore. They're similar, but have somewhat different performance characteristics.