# Firebase Connection Managment - multiple subscriptions on similar objects

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Inside app (Android/iOS-swift) I have list of friends of local user - they can check-in and I would like to subscribe to updates to each friends (as we don't send pushes for those changes).
However question is - if I establish lets say 100 or 200 "onDataChange" listeners (for each friend on list) - would this count as 100 or 200 open connections to server or Firebase can manage them better (for example 1 open connection for multiple same class objects)?
Is this a good practice?

Comment: @DevidFarinelli so (if I get linked post correct) this would mean that one connection is established even for multiple friend listeners?
Also - would it be a good practice with 100-200 or even much more listeners (friend number)?

Comment: Yes, according to this (http://stackoverflow.com/a/27592618/4695325) :)