# Firebase Node listeners and connections for one to one and group chat application

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am making a chat application with firebase, where user can chat in a group or one to one chat. As per design of firebase database, a node have to be created per chat session, and both users will listen to that node.  Suppose there are thousand users, and each user is chatting to multiple users. Is it a good design that all users listen to the chat nodes individually. Does it will impact performance? Is this a good architecture? Also if a user  will be treated as single connection or multiple if single user listens to multiple nodes simultaneously.

Comment: " Also if a user will be treated as single connection or multiple if single user listens to multiple nodes simultaneously." This was asked recently and marked as a duplicate. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38141577/firebase-connection-managment-multiple-subscriptions-on-similar-objects

Comment: The rest of this is really an incredibly broad topic, that cannot be generically answered. I recommend reading some more about [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/)