# Firebase how to add new data to all child

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My Firebase Data.

```
User : {
    user1 : {
         name : 1,
         age : 2
    },
    user2 : {
         name : 1,
         age : 2
    },
      ....
      ....
      ....
   user10 : {
         name : 1,
         age : 2
    }
}
```

I need add ***somekey*** to all user. not use loop each.

```
userxx : {
      name : 1,
      age : 2,
      somekey : 1
}
```

current code :

```
fb.ref("Users").once('value',function(s){
     s.forEach(function(snap){
        fb.ref("Users/"+snap.key+"/somekey").set(2);
     });
});
```

if small data this code is work, there might be a problem if large data have user 100+ .

thanks and sorry for grammar.

Comment: `not use loop each.` why not? That's pretty much your only choice, whether you write it explicitly or use a method which loops internally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Listeners are inexpensive: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27583746/firebase-limit-on-the-number-of-observers-listeners)

Anyway in this case you can use multi-path [update](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/09/introducing-multi-location-updates-and_86.html). Here's an example:

```
fb.ref("Users").update({
    'user1/somekey': 2,
    'user2/somekey': 2
})
```

You can probably change your code this way

```
fb.ref("Users").once('value',function(s){
     var users = s.val()
     var newUsers = {}
     for(var key in users) {
         newUsers[key+'somekey'] = 2
     }
     fb.ref("Users").update(newUsers)
});
```

Hope it helps ;)

Comment: Thanks. it helps :)