# How to watch the events of more than 10+ Firebase Child nodes at once?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm not allowed to Change the current structure of my Firebase DB cause it is wired to so many other things.
I have a DB structure similar to this.

```
notifications/1
    - 1
        2 - data about notification from group 1
        3 - data about notification from group 1
    - 2
        3 - data about notification from group 1
        4 - data about notification from group 1        

notifications/3
    - 1
        2 - data about notification from group 3
        3 - data about notification from group 3
    - 2
        3 - data about notification from group 3
        4 - data about notification from group 3
```

If I want to watch more than 12 groups at once and if I write something similar to this...Is this a bad practice?

```
watchForNotification(3);
watchForNotification(1);
watchForNotification(2);

function watchForNotification(groupId){
    var notificationReference         =  firebase.database().ref('notifications/'+groupId);
    notificationReference.on("child_added", function(snap) {
        ///....
            // Code here to show the notification in its respect Div
    });
}
```

Also, How many connections can I make at once? What's the best way to Achieve this? Hope someone could help me.

Comment: I'm currently doing something similar on Android and attaching a listener per group is the only way. It is hectic, but we see no other way to manage it.

Comment: There is no hard limit on the number of listeners that your app can have. All listeners from a single app connect over the same web socket, so they're only as expensive as the data they listen for (which seems quite small in your case). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27583746/firebase-limit-on-the-number-of-observers-listeners