# Is it a good practice to have big number of childEventListeners?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

I write an app with firebase, where user can display events in his surroundings through GeoFire. Geofire returns me list of eventIDs, and then i download these events. The problem is, that i need to listen for changes in these events. is it a good practice to register childEventListener for every event (there can be a big number of them, lets say 100)? Or is there i better approach?

Thank for any help, Honza

**edit:**

Events are sportEvents with fields like: title, description, time, place, signedUsers and so on. After I download events in my surroundings i need to listen for changes, so i can display, who will participate in this event (for example football match) and so on.

At first i download eventIDs in area around me with help of geofire

```
    private  ObservableOnSubscribe<String> suggestedEventIDSource(@NonNull LatLng userLocation, int wantedNumberOfEvents, List<String> sports){
    return (e->{
        ArrayList<String> suggestedEventIDs = new ArrayList<>();


        final GeoQuery geoQuery = geoFire.queryAtLocation(new GeoLocation(userLocation.latitude,userLocation.longitude),radius);

        GeoQueryEventListener geoQueryEventListener = new GeoQueryEventListener(){

            @Override
            public void onKeyEntered(String key, GeoLocation location) {
                String[] idParts = key.split(" ");
                if((sports.size() == 0 || sports.contains(idParts[0]))
                        && !(idParts[idParts.length-1]).equals(currentUser.getUid())
                        && !(Meet2SportApp.getSignedEventIDV2().contains(key))){
                    suggestedEventIDs.add(key);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onKeyExited(String key) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onKeyMoved(String key, GeoLocation location) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onGeoQueryReady() {
                Log.i(TAG, "onGeoQueryReady: radius - " + radius + " events in radius - " + suggestedEventIDs.size());

                if(suggestedEventIDs.size()<wantedNumberOfEvents && radius < 50f){
                    radius++;
                    e.onComplete();
                }
                else {
                    for(String eventID : suggestedEventIDs)
                         e.onNext(eventID);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onGeoQueryError(DatabaseError error) {

            }
        };


        geoQuery.addGeoQueryEventListener(geoQueryEventListener);
        e.setCancellable(geoQuery::removeAllListeners);
    });
}
```

And then i download each event using valueEventListener

```
 private SingleOnSubscribe<DataSnapshot> sourceOfEvent(String eventID){
    return (e -> {
        RxJavaPlugins.setErrorHandler(Functions.emptyConsumer());
        Log.i(TAG, "Downloading event: " + eventID + " on thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                e.onSuccess(dataSnapshot);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            }
        };
        eventDB.child(eventID).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
    });
}
```

That works fine, but when some changes happens, app is not updated. 
So if i use childEventListener instead of valueEventListener, i would be notified when some changes happen, but i would have potencialy a big number of active childEventListeners.

So is this a good practice, or there is a better way?

Comment: Exactly **how** do events ***change*** after they occur?

Comment: I am assuming that events are fired on an eventID. So he wants to catch all events on all eventIDs? I would assume one `childEventListener` that simply checks which eventID fired the event should be sufficient.

It would be really nice if you could rephrase your question because currently it is really unclear what you are asking. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiyable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Event are sport Events, for example there is event "Football match" and user who created can edit time, or place. When other user sign to this event, it changes numberOfSignedUsers field and so on...

Comment: With that explanation you should REALLY expand your original question, explain the words you are using, show us the code you are working with and show us exactly where your issue is.

Comment: @Ben  Question was updated, i hope that it is more clear :)

Comment: Have 100 concurrent listeners is not a big deal. See Rob's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27583746/firebase-limit-on-the-number-of-observers-listeners. But don't keep a child event listener for all children. Instead keep using `ValueEventListener` for each individual child, just attach it with `addValueEventListener`.

Comment: I created a helper class where i have one valueEventListener and methods with parameter Firebase ref, by which i register and unregister this valueEventListener to/from these Firebase references like suggested  JPCProgrammer bellow. Hope it is the right approach. Thanks a lot for help guys :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes you can have multiple ChildEventListeners is it a good practice no. You should really use one and have a LinkedHashMap type structure so that you can allocate your data to a certain Key which you can then call back later on.

Comment: Would you be so kind and give me example please? I'm not sure, how you ment it. I can have a list or map of Firebase references to nodes, i want to observe (to sportevents), but i am not sure, how can i add single childeventlistener to multiple nodes in firebase. If it can be done somehow, it would be perfect...

Comment: Could you explain more clearly how this firbase process work does it grab each sporting event 1 by 1 or in chucks. If it is one by one u can make a loop to grab all the values of data and then shove it into a linkedhasmap.

Comment: firstly by geofire, app downloads all IDs of event, which are in for example 1 kilometr area. Then singleValueEventListener is registered for each sportEvent (which reference is found thanks to eventID) and by that, i download these sportevents. If I register childEventListener instead of singleValueEventListener, whenever sportEvent changes in firebase the app would be notified and it downloads updated sportEvent. But I would have as many registered childEventListeners as there are SportEvents in  given area...

Comment: You should assign all the IDs of each event to one Listener then sort through the data that you get.